# Redirect whole domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

is it possible to redirect entire domain to another?

I want it to redirect this way:

```
domain.com/something --> www.domain.eu/something
sub.domain.com/folder/file.type --> sub.domain.eu/folder/file.type
super.mega.sub.domain.com --> super.mega.sub.domain.eu
```

(For any subdomain and anything after /.)

I have access only to com domain.

So far I have invented this code for .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But it work like:

```
sub.domain.com/something --> www.domain.eu/sub/something
```

So it is wrong.
Any help please?
Thanks very much.

Comment: i guess u may use the other domain as alias instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of what you have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]

# for all subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I noticed that Chrome redirects sub.domain.com to sub.domain.eu/sub

Answer (score 0):

Ok I assume that you want to redirect your whole domain to another and not just a single page..

So simply write the following lines in your htaccess file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourolddomain.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourolddomain.com$

RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.yournewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

I usually just create an index.html file and redirect it with a Meta Tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.newdomain.ext">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://subdomain.newdomain.ext">
```